# How to dismiss built-in zoom controls in WebView when switching to another WebView instance?

Tags: android, android-layout

I use WebViews with built-in zoom controls enabled in combination with ViewPager so that I can swipe between WebView instances.

Now if I activate zoom by sliding down or up on the screen, the zoom controls appear and stay visible for a defined time even if I swipe to another page. It would be OK if worked on the current page, but they belong to the previous one and do nothing, only take place and confuse users who must wait until they dismiss to be able to zoom on a new page...

I have spent a couple of hours searching for any hint but with no luck. There is [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164603/is-there-a-way-to-hide-and-show-the-zoom-controls-on-a-webview) here on SO but with no relevant answers :(

Is it even possible?