# Disable Zoom Control in WebView using API 7 Android

Tags: android, webview, zooming

I'd like to disable zoom control in WebView. I'm using this code to hide the control :

```
web.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
```

but this code can use in Android since API 11, and how to disable it using API 7 ??

Comment: You may be able to do it using reflection. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164603/is-there-a-way-to-hide-and-show-the-zoom-controls-on-a-webview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out: [enable/disable zoom in Android WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5125851/enable-disable-zoom-in-android-webview)
There is an implementation there for what you are asking to achieve.